# Generate a full URL in a Mailer view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

in mailer view:

```
      <%= url_for(controller:'resas', action: 'show', only_path: false) %>
```

rake routes:

```
                      resa GET    /resas/:id(.:format)             resas#show
```

Here is the exception when trying to generate the e-mail:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"resas"}
```

My host is parametered (as localhost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass in an id for the show route. Try

```
<%= url_for(controller:'resas', action: 'show', id: @resa.id, only_path: false) %>
```

(Not sure how your resource is named)

Answer (score 0):

At the least your route syntax is incorrect. Try:

```
#routes.rb
GET    /resas/:id(.:format), to: resas#show
```

Read all about routes and route syntax in the rails documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

It also looks like you might want to reconsider `only_path: false` without providing a host name.  Read more about url_for and only_path here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html

Comment: sorry but I do not understand your answer.
My host is configured in the dev environment.
When I do rake routes I have the route resas#show defined so what's the problem?

Comment: url_for does not know that. There are two very good paragraphs in the documentation I linked for you that explain it.

Comment: And your route syntax doesn't match the documentation, or work in my apps, but if it's working for you that may not be the issue.